# One-to-many and many-to-many relation between nodes of different content types

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I am using [Relation](https://drupal.org/project/relation) module for creating relationship. But i didn't find the option how to create one to many, many to many relation. 
Can anybody tell me regarding that
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Relation module itself provides a block that can be used to create relations, you can [create a simple relations by configuring relations and entity collector](http://vimeo.com/28188846) or can use the [Rules module to create relations](http://vimeo.com/28479420).

If your want to set up a relationship between entities than you may use the [relation_add module](https://drupal.org/project/relation_add): It provides a block that allows the user to add an appropriate relation from an entity page to any other appropriate entities, with a generic autocomplete for each endpoint, and relation fields. [Tutorial for relation add module](http://vimeo.com/30394452).

Tutorials for creating a relation type (`administration toolbar > Structure > Relation types`):
https://drupal.org/node/1276284
http://nodeone.se/en/creating-a-first-relation-type-the-entity-collector
http://nodeone.se/en/directional-relations-and-fields-on-relations

Few Tutorials that may be useful for you:
http://vimeo.com/28178686
http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-relation-module
https://drupal.org/node/1276298
https://drupal.org/node/1276380